# Check If an element isn't visible on div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="ris" class="alert alert-info">
    <div id="one">
        <p>.....</p>
    </div>
    <section id="toggle" class="toggle>
        <label</label> 
        <div id="" class="toggle-content">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

```js
if ($('section').css('display') == 'none') {
    $("#one").show();
}
else {
    $("#one").hide();
}
```

Selector `:visible` does not work, I tried with CSS `display`, nothing. I would like to know if you can make visible the div `#one` when the section is not visible. In my actual code, there are more sections.

Comment: Is this a typo in your question, or actually in your code: `<label</label>` ?

Comment: As well as: `<li>><li>`

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Barring typos, what you have there should actually work, assuming A) You only have one `section` element on the page (the one you've shown); B) The way you've hidden it (you haven't, in your question) is via `display: none` (as opposed to `visibility: hidden` or positioning it off-page); C) Your JavaScript code is actually in a `script` tag, and actually after the elements it relates to; D) You're including jQuery on the page somewhere before your code.

Comment: When asking for help, at least take the time to format your markup reasonably, check for typos, form complete sentences (get a friend or colleague to help if you need it), etc. You're asking people to take time for you; make it easy for them.

Comment: I apologize for writing the wrong code , I am writing in a hurry . however, the syntax is correct , I tried the work is visible .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help: `$('section').is(':visible')`

```js
if ($('section').is(':visible')) {
  $("#one").show();
} else {
  $("#one").hide();
}
```

```css
section {
  display: block;
  /* display: none; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ris" class="alert alert-info">
  <div id="one">
    <p>.....</p>
  </div>
  <section id="toggle" class="toggle>
  <label></label> 
  <div id=" "class="toggle-content ">
  <ul>
    <li>  </li>
    <li>  </li>
    <li>  </li>
    <li>  </li>
    <li>  </li>
    <li>  </li>
    <li>  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```